# Can anybody explain me this behaviour?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I can't understand why this

```
using System.Configuration;
ExeConfigurationFileMap temp = ExeConfigurationFileMap(CustomConfigFilePath)
```

is not working . But, the below line is working fine.

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap temp = ExeConfigurationFileMap{ ExeConfigFilename = CustomConfigFilePath };
```

Check it yourself. I am using .Net 4.0 in Windows 7 - 64 bit. I suspect it as a bug.

Note: No need of deep dive. put one break point after this line. In execution you can see that the first style(on above) didn't put any value on the variable "ExeConfigFilename". But the second style does.

**EDIT:** 
   Even though the answers are pretty good, I am voting to close this. The reason is it wont be useful for anybody. It just dumps the space. So, please vote to close this.

Comment: Aren't you missing `new` somewhere in there ?

Comment: What is the type of CustomConfigFilePath? Is it your custom configuration file path?

Comment: @PrasanthVJ the CustomConfigFilePath should be a string.

Comment: "is not working" is not an error. Please share the exact compiler error you get.

Comment: @Luc Sorry. I made the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all; I assume that your code should invoke constructors, but you're missing the `new` keyword.

To answer your question:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap temp = new ExeConfigurationFileMap(CustomConfigFilePath);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap temp = new ExeConfigurationFileMap
{
     MachineConfigFilename = CustomConfigFilePath 
};
```

The [constructor argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395351%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is for `MachineConfigFilename` and not for `ExeConfigFilename`, which you're assuming.

That's probably why one works and the other won't.

Comment: Object initalizers should allow you to assign to any property, shouldn't it ?

Comment: @LucMorin: Yes, any settable property. But that has nothing to do with this question/answer, right?

Comment: I think it does. Isn't his second snippet using the object initializer syntax ?

Comment: @LucMorin: Yes, but the second snippet sets the `ExeConfigFilename` property. The first snippet, however, assigns the `MachineConfigFilename` property. That's what I'm trying to say in my answer.

Comment: DOH!, I just realized it's his first snippet that's not working. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The source code of the ExeConfigurationFileMap is:

```
public sealed class ExeConfigurationFileMap : ConfigurationFileMap 
{
    string  _exeConfigFilename;
    string  _roamingUserConfigFilename;
    string  _localUserConfigFilename;

    public ExeConfigurationFileMap(string machineConfigFileName)
            : base(machineConfigFileName) 
    {
        _exeConfigFilename = String.Empty;
        _roamingUserConfigFilename = String.Empty;
        _localUserConfigFilename = String.Empty;
    }

    public string ExeConfigFilename 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _exeConfigFilename;
        }
        set 
        {
            _exeConfigFilename = value;
        }
    }
```

And you can see how setted field `_exeConfigFilename` through the property and the constructor.

Comment: The .NET Framework source code is an implementation detail which may change between versions. Please refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395351(v=vs.110).aspx), as that is a contract to which you can assume the implementing class to comply.

Comment: @CodeCaster You're right, but sometimes it is the fastest way to see how something works. No documentation is not relevant as the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean the following.

```
    ExeConfigurationFileMap temp
    = new ExeConfigurationFileMap(){ ExeConfigFilename = CustomConfigFilePath };
```

The first version isn't working since the constructor which takes a string as an argument assigns it to a member different from `ExecConfigFilename`.